# Jdeveloper rendering messed up on Linux when JSF Designer

Tags: linux, java-2d, jdeveloper, ati

I have installed Jdeveloper 11g on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
After trying to edit the jsf page in the design mode the Jdeveloper becomes completely messed up like on the page below.

[image]

I tried different versions of java 32 and 64 bit and the result is the same.
So when trying to use visual jsf editor, the jdeveloper is pracricaly unusable.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I came to the conclusion that the problem is related to the graphic card driver for the ATI hd 7600M graphic card in my laptop.
I tried replacing the driver but the result remained the same.

Finally I came up with a fix:
After I added this line in the the jdev.conf:

```
AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
```

Jdeveloper started working fine.

I hope this will be of help to someone.